# Modal in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, ngroute

How to launch a modal in angularjs when routeprovider is used.

```
$('#loginmodal').modal("show");
```

throws an error when used with routeprovider but works when launched in an individual page. Help me

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: The modal is not launching

Comment: is your console saying the same in error msg?

Comment: When the above code is used other angular functions do not work. Eg:-$scope.msg = "Hello" prints {{msg}} in the html page. When not used html page prints Hello

Comment: can u give a plunker with the issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Jquery in angular-js.

I would prefer to use the [uib-modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). It is a twitter bootstrap modal written completely in angularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open the modal using jQuery which is not advisable.

Suggesting you not to trigger the modal in the angular function.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
ng-click="modalClicked()"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Here is a [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DSlQaMzEOnO4qBZPgt1D) to help